# JqGrid shows success in load, but does not mount the Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm with a grid on my site. I use the jqGrid. What is happening is that when the data back the request, they are formatted the right way because the jqGrid itself enters `LoadComplete` method, but it does not load the data in the Grid.
Javascript is JqGrid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'adm/controller/medico.php?acao=listarMedico',
    mtype: "POST",
    styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
      { label: 'id', name: 'idMedico', key: true, width: 75, hidden:true },
      { label: 'Nome', name: 'nomeMedico', width: 75 },
      { label: 'CRM', name: 'crmMedico', width: 150 },
      { label: 'Especialidades', name: 'especialidadesMedico', width: 150 },
      { label: 'Endereço', name: 'enderecoMedico', width: 150 },
      { label: 'Telefone', name: 'telefoneMedico', width: 150 }
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 40, 100],
    //height: "auto",
    height: 400,
    emptyrecords: "Nenhum médico com o filtro selecionado",
    loadtext: "Buscando e carregando...",
    rowNum: 20,
    pager: "#jqGridPager",
    caption: "Médicos Conveniados",
    loadComplete: function(data){
      console.log('sucesso');
      console.log(data);
    },
    loadError: function (xhr,st,err) {
      console.log('HTTP status code: ' + xhr.status + '\n' +
        'textStatus: ' + st + '\n' +
        'errorThrown: ' + err);
      console.log('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

The return of PHP is this JSON:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":20,"rows":{"1":{"id":"1","cell":{"idMedico":"1","nomeMedico":"dsda","crmMedico"
:"jknjk","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico":" ,  -  - ","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"2":{"id"
:"2","cell":{"idMedico":"2","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:" ,  -  - ","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"3":{"id":"3","cell":{"idMedico":"3","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico"
:"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico":" ,  -  - ","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"4":{"id":"4"
,"cell":{"idMedico":"4","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:" ,  -  - ","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"5":{"id":"5","cell":{"idMedico":"5","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico"
:"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico":"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte
 - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"6":{"id":"5","cell":{"idMedico":"5","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico"
:"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico":"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte
 - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"7":{"id":"5","cell":{"idMedico":"5","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico"
:"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico":"Endereco , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico"
:"() "}},"8":{"id":"5","cell":{"idMedico":"5","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico"
:null,"enderecoMedico":"Endereco , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"9":{"id"
:"6","cell":{"idMedico":"6","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:" ,  -  - ","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"10":{"id":"7","cell":{"idMedico":"7","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico"
:"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico":" ,  -  - ","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"11":{"id":"8"
,"cell":{"idMedico":"8","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"12":{"id":"8","cell":
{"idMedico":"8","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"13":{"id":"9","cell":
{"idMedico":"9","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"14":{"id":"9","cell":
{"idMedico":"9","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endereco , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"15":{"id":"10","cell":
{"idMedico":"10","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"(81) 98125-8886"}},"16":{"id"
:"10","cell":{"idMedico":"10","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endereco , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"17":{"id":"11","cell":
{"idMedico":"11","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"(81) 98200-5300"}},"18":{"id"
:"11","cell":{"idMedico":"11","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"(81) 98125-8886"}},"19":{"id"
:"11","cell":{"idMedico":"11","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endereco , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte - ES","telefoneMedico":"() "}},"20":{"id":"12","cell":
{"idMedico":"12","nomeMedico":"Henrique","crmMedico":"CRM","especialidadesMedico":null,"enderecoMedico"
:"Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES","telefoneMedico":"(81) 98200-5300"}}}}
```

What the problem, someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data which you generates seems to have wrong format. The value of `"rows"` property looks like

```
{
    "1":{"id":"1","cell":{"idMedico":"1",...}},
    "2":{"id":"2","cell":{"idMedico":"2",...}},
    ...
    "20":{"id":"12","cell":{"idMedico":"12",...}}
}
```

instead of

```
[
    {"id":"1","cell":["1",...]},
    {"id":"2","cell":["2",...}},
    ...
    {"id":"12","cell":["12"...]}
]
```

or better

```
[
    {"idMedico":"1",...},
    {"idMedico":"2",...},
    ...
    {"idMedico":"12",...}
]
```

You should change the format of `"rows"` property of returned data.

I remind you that `[]` represent JSON serialized **array** and `{}` represent JSON serialized **object**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Oleg. The problem was that even though you said I decided creating an array in a key and moving the columns to it.